# Error when launching Java app on desktop using LibGdx/Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl, libgdx

I'm using LibGdx to develop a Java-based game. I haven't decided whether I want the game to be deployed on Android or PC, so I figured I can at least develop+test on desktop and then decide. I've used LibGdx before and it worked fine.. but that must been before I did a complete system wipe (as I like to do a few times per year).

Anyhow, when I try to launch the game in Eclipse as "Java Application" I get the following errors:

-`Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: OpenGL is not supported by the video driver.`

-`Caused by: org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated`

Clearly this is caused by my GPU.. so I installed the latest drivers for my (integrated) video chip, but no dice. Anyone know anything about the "Pixel format" part of this? I haven't really done *anything* code-wise yet, I just have a blank application that I'm trying to get to display on my PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the Jogl backend a try. Double check your drivers. What GPU do you have?

Comment: Thank you badlogic :) Jogl worked fine. Just FYI, my gpu is ATI Mobility HD2600