# Exception in launch application in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

```
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.title = "my-gdx-game";
    cfg.useGL20 = false;
    cfg.width = 480;
    cfg.height = 320;

    new LwjglApplication(new MyGdxGame(), cfg);
```

I use this code in my desktop launcher class, but I get GdxRuntimeException: OpenGL is not supported by the video driver.
    any help ?

Comment: Please include the full backtrace (especially any "Caused by:" exceptions) there are a lot of useful details in there.

Answer (score 1):

Its probably because:

```
 OpenGL is not supported by your video driver
```

Libgdx on the desktop requires at least OpenGL 1.5 be supported by your desktop video card (to emulate OpengGL ES 1.x).  OpenGL should be included with your OS's graphics card drivers (you should include details about your platform in your question).  See the [OpenGL Getting Started Wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Downloading_OpenGL) for some hints.

See also [libGDX Exception in thread "LWJGL Application"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972688/libgdx-exception-in-thread-lwjgl-application)