# OpenGL is not supported by the video driver

Tags: java, libgdx

When I use this code:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
      cfg.title = "MtxJungleGameMenu";
      cfg.useGL20 = false;
      cfg.width = 800;
      cfg.height = 480;
      new LwjglApplication(new MainStarter(), cfg);
   }
}
```

I get an exception like this:

> Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: OpenGL is not supported by the video driver.

any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [libGDX Exception in thread "LWJGL Application"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972688/libgdx-exception-in-thread-lwjgl-application)

Answer (score 12):

Put this code 
    System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.allowSoftwareOpenGL", "true");

Problem solved in my case.. this will allow libgdx to run as software openGL mode.

Your code will look like this.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
      System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.allowSoftwareOpenGL", "true");
      cfg.title = "MtxJungleGameMenu";
      cfg.useGL20 = false;
      cfg.width = 800;
      cfg.height = 480;
      new LwjglApplication(new MainStarter(), cfg);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your video drivers.

Basically the display drivers for your P.C

Answer (score 1):

i had a problem just like it and fixed it by downgrading to **jdk 8 update 45.**

i was using win 10 along with the integrated Intel HD 2000 for graphics .