# LWJGL reports that OpenGL is not supported on a modern nvidia card

Tags: libgdx, lwjgl

So i have been trying out libgdx for the past day and it works well, until i realized that it only works on my laptop with intel graphics while it instantly shuts down on my desktop with a nvidia 750ti.

According to [this github issue](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/997), this issue should've already been fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/commit/48c9299fcb011d7c3ce3035de74c0c3363363512).

I also tried what others on older posts have recommended, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23989958/2127148) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23042209/2127148) (which shouldn't be neccessary anymore since that commit, but worth trying)

```
System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.allowSoftwareOpenGL", "true");
```

But believe it or not, it doesn't work. Here's the stack trace

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: OpenGL is not supported by the video driver.
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.createDisplayPixelFormat(LwjglGraphics.java:229)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setupDisplay(LwjglGraphics.java:174)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:138)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
Caused by: org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: X Error - disp: 0x7f0f4c000c50 serial: 194 error: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation) request_code: 154 minor_code: 24
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.globalErrorHandler(LinuxDisplay.java:320)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxContextImplementation.nCreate(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxContextImplementation.create(LinuxContextImplementation.java:51)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextGL.<init>(ContextGL.java:132)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:850)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.createDisplayPixelFormat(LwjglGraphics.java:220)
    ... 3 more
```

When comparing the stack trace to [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972688/libgdx-exception-in-thread-lwjgl-application), the cause is aparently not `Pixel format is not accelerated` rather `Caused by: org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: X Error - disp: 0x7f12cc000c50 serial: 194 error: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation) request_code: 154 minor_code: 24`.
Maybe that's just because i'm running linux and he isn't, i don't know. It does seem wierd though that a `integer parameter out of range for operation` error would be the reason for LWJGL to think that my video driver doesn't support OpenGL, but that's just a guess.

[Here is the exact code that i'm trying to run](https://github.com/johan-bjareholt/DV1549-project/tree/24b6c373a08c776ff2347e859908d643d694011b). I don't think the code is to blame since it works just fine on my laptop, but i've added it here just in case.

Both my laptop and desktop runs up-to-date Arch Linux installs, so the os shouldn't be the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The github issue is for a hardware device that is too old to support LWJGL.  I think your case is different.  Do any OpenGL apps work for you?  (Can you get `glxgears` working?)

Comment: Thanks, it was something wrong with OpenGL and a simple restart solved it for me. glxinfo and glxgears simply crashed when i started them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was pretty simple, thanks [P.T.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/960524/p-t) for the help.

I don't know what was wrong, but no OpenGL apps could be run at all actually, and a simple reboot solved the issue for me.

Answer (score -2):

> Open Software & Updates

> Additional Drivers

> Using X.Org X server - Nouveau display drivers from xserver-xorg-video-mouveau (open source)

> Apply Changes

> Open terminal

> sudo reboot now

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).