# OpenGL is not supported by the video card

Tags: opengl, libgdx, blender

I used to run and test libgdx game on blender when i had win 7 and it worked fine with Intel HD Graphics 3000 driver then after i installed win 10 and copied the same files with same version of blender and libgdx it shows me an error "OpenGL is not supported by the video card" but the video card is the same what should i do?

Comment: Check this out... https://stackoverflow.com/a/23042209/3677457 - Otherwise, update your video card drivers???

Comment: i tried it before unfortunately didn't work thx for help anyway

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 10 installer doesn't setup feature complete OpenGL drivers. You'll have to download the right drivers for your GPU from the vendor's website and install them manually.

Comment: But i checked it by automatic update and it is uptodate is that sufficient or should i manually download it?

Comment: @Shefo: To make a long story short: Microsoft is actively sabotaging OpenGL support by stripping away modern OpenGL features from all graphics drivers installed through any automatic Windows installation or updating method. You *absolutely* must download and install the drivers from the GPU vendor website. Some applications, like for example Valve Steam will do driver feature checks and initiate an download/update if required for a particular situation.

Comment: actually i downloaded intel hd graphics 3000 from intel's website and installed it stills show me that error